# How to get the longest string length from an array of lists from each lists matching index?

Tags: python, string, list

I have an array of lists in the form

```
list = [['hello','hi','hey'],['where','when','why'],['him','herself','themselves']]
```

I want to compare the length of `list[0][0]` to `list[1][0]` and `list[2][0]`, basically all the first indexes, and obtain the length of the longest string size.

it must iterate through the list because the number of items and number of lists in the list can be any size.

for example, the answer of this should be

```
length1 = 5
length2 = 6 #('herself' is longer than 'hi' and 'when')
length3 = 10
```

TIA!

Comment: Please include your code that is not producing the desired output

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far and the results you got.

Comment: I think you want `length2 = 7` as `'herself'` has 7 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a variable number of variables. You can use either a list comprehension or a dictionary:

```
L = [['hello','hi','hey'],['where','when','why'],['him','herself','themselves']]

# list comprehension
res_list = [max(map(len, i)) for i in zip(*L)]

[5, 7, 10]

# dictionary from enumerated generator expression
res_dict = dict(enumerate((max(map(len, i)) for i in zip(*L)), 1))

{1: 5, 2: 7, 3: 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the triples from [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and print out the length of the longest word:

```
lst = [['hello','hi','hey'],['where','when','why'],['him','herself','themselves']]

for i, triple in enumerate(zip(*lst), start=1):
    print('length%d = %d' % (i, len(max(triple, key=len))))

# length1 = 5
# length2 = 7
# length3 = 10
```

Or as a dictionary:

```
{'length%d' % i: len(max(e, key=len)) for i, e in enumerate(zip(*lst), start=1)}
# {'length1': 5, 'length2': 7, 'length3': 10}
```

Which is nicer than storing variables for each length.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do it in Python.

```
array = [['hello','hi','hey'],
         ['where','when','why'],
         ['him','herself','themselves']]

length1 = 0
for elem in array:
    if length1 < len(elem[0]):
        length1 = len(elem[0])

length2 = max(array, key=lambda elem: len(elem[1]))

from itertools import accumulate
length3 = accumulate(array,
        lambda e1, e2: max(len(e1[2]), len(e2[2]))
```

As a side note it is generally not recommended to assign something to standard identifiers, like `list`.